# datamodel for a warehouse

Tags: database, database-design

I need a database for configuring a warehouse. So far i have 3 tables:

- Warehouse (1) has many Lanes (n)
- Lanes (1) has many Racks (n)
- Racks (1) has many Shelves

Now each tables has obvious a ID and a description / name.

The Shelves table contains a stack_id (pallet), so i can keep track which shelves are taken and which are free, and which stack is located where.

One of my problems is that each lane can contain a different amount of racks. For example. Lane A has 10 racks, where Lane B has 8 racks. So just setting-up a simple matrix (lanes * racks * shelves is not working).

I need to be able to calc. warehouse occupancy, and of course be able to trace where a specific stack is located.

My question is: do I really needed to use 3 separate tables for this? Is there a better way of doing this?

And another question is: if the naming chosen (Lanes, Racks and Shelves) are the correct (I'm not native english).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can solve your "irregular matrix" problem by inverting the path: a shelve has a parent rack. a rack has a parent lane. A lane lives in a warehouse. So:every object only needs a parent pointer, and more than one objects can point to the same parent. You can combine the levels of the model into a recursive model. You can even put constraints on that (a lane cannot have a rack as a parent)

Comment: Are you suggesting to use of that with just one table? Basically a parent_id column and a attribute for the type of record (warehouse, lane, rack, shelf)?

Comment: Yes, that's basically my point. Is is rather hard in recursive models to put constraints on the topology ("no more than twelve boxes per rack"), but *in most cases* reality will put enough constraints on that. And if you're Dutch: read Veldwijk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If lanes can have different numbers of racks, it makes good sense to store that information in a table.

```
-- Predicate: "Warehouse number <warehouse_num> is called <warehouse_name>."
create table warehouses (
  warehouse_num integer primary key,
  warehouse_name varchar(45) not null unique
);

-- Predicate: "Warehouse number <warehouse_num> contains lane <lane_num>."
-- This table allows different numbers of lanes per warehouse. If you change
-- the data type to, say, varchar(2) or varchar(3), you can accommodate 
-- different lane "names" in each warehouse. For example, one warehouse 
-- might name its lanes "Lane 1" and "Lane 2", while a different warehouse 
-- might use "Lane A" and "Lane B2".
create table lanes (
  warehouse_num integer not null references warehouses (warehouse_num),
  lane_num integer not null check (lane_num > 0),
  primary key (warehouse_num, lane_num)
);

-- Predicate: "Lane <lane_num> in warehouse <warehouse_num> contains rack 
-- <rack_num>."
-- Allows a different number of racks in each lane.
create table racks (
  warehouse_num integer not null,
  lane_num integer not null,
  rack_num integer not null check (rack_num > 0),
  primary key (warehouse_num, lane_num, rack_num),
  foreign key        (warehouse_num, lane_num) 
    references lanes (warehouse_num, lane_num)
);

-- Predicate: "Rack <rack_num> in lane <lane_num> in warehouse 
-- <warehouse_num> contains shelf <shelf_num>."  Allows a different
--  number of shelves in each rack.
create table shelves (
  warehouse_num integer not null,
  lane_num integer not null,
  rack_num integer not null,
  shelf_num integer not null check (shelf_num > 0),
  primary key (warehouse_num, lane_num, rack_num, shelf_num),
  foreign key        (warehouse_num, lane_num, rack_num) 
    references racks (warehouse_num, lane_num, rack_num)
);

-- "Contents" might be a better name than inventory.  You might also need 
-- a unique constraint on stack_id. 
-- Predicate: "Stack <stack_id> is stored in warehouse <warehouse_num> in lane 
-- <lane_num> in rack <rack_num> on shelf <shelf_num>."
create table inventory (
  warehouse_num integer not null,
  lane_num integer not null,
  rack_num integer not null,
  shelf_num integer not null,
  stack_id integer not null,
  primary key (warehouse_num, lane_num, rack_num, shelf_num, stack_id),
  foreign key (warehouse_num, lane_num, rack_num, shelf_num)
    references shelves (warehouse_num, lane_num, rack_num, shelf_num)
);
```

I'm assuming that lanes, racks, and shelves are numbered. If they're not, use their names instead. By using actual lane names, rack names, and shelf names instead of meaningless id numbers, queries on inventory need no joins to produce human-readable results. It will be ripping fast, even if your warehouse is a distribution center.

The foreign key constraints between tables give you a really high degree of data integrity, at least as far as identifying shelves, racks, etc. Most of them will need to be filled only once, and updated only when you reconfigure a warehouse's lanes and racks.

Terminology: Your "lanes" might be more commonly called aisles or rows.  I've never seen a row in a warehouse called a lane in English, but I understand what you mean.  Whoever you're building this for will tell you if you ask them.